# android-cts-4.4-r3 gives NoClassDefFoundError while running cts-tradefed

Tags: android, cygwin, android-4.4-kitkat, cts, android-cts

I am trying to run Android CTS tests on Windows using Cygwin for android-cts-4.4_r3-linux_x86-arm.

When I run ./cts-tradefed I get following error:

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/android/cts/tradefed/command/CtsConsole
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.android.cts.tradefed.command.CtsConsole
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
Could not find the main class: com.android.cts.tradefed.command.CtsConsole.  Program will exit.
Exception in thread "main"

Do I need to modify cts-tradefed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The cts-tradefed file in only for linux I guess. For windows you have to create new batch file. e.g. cts_run.bat and put below code in file. Make sure you give path according to your system. Below code worked for Lollipop.

```
set SDK_ROOT=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_67
java -Xmx512M -cp C:\Users\Desktop\android-cts-5.0_r2-linux_x86-arm\android-cts\tools\cts-tradefed.jar;C:\Users\Desktop\android-cts-5.0_r2-linux_x86-arm\android-cts\tools\hosttestlib.jar;C:\Users\Desktop\android-cts-5.0_r2-linux_x86-arm\android-cts\tools\ddmlib-prebuilt.jar;C:\Users\Desktop\android-cts-5.0_r2-linux_x86-arm\android-cts\tools\tradefed-prebuilt.jar -DCTS_ROOT=C:\Users\Desktop\android-cts-5.0_r2-linux_x86-arm com.android.cts.tradefed.command.CtsConsole
```